# Mead Problem with Yeast

Tags: fermentation, yeast

So the other day I created a mead and messed up... long story short I killed all my yeast by rushing. I added the dead yeast into my mead and it all sank to the bottom. I just racked off the dead yeast and now I'm trying to decide weather to re start my mead or just add new yeast. My only concern is my mead has a destinct smell of yeast. Well this smell go away or is there a way to remove it. I'm planning on only fermenting this mead for 3 months

Comment: How long does it sit without fermentation?

Answer (score 3):

fresh yeast should get rid of most of yeast smell. And even if they don't, a package of yeast is far cheaper than ingredients for new batch of mead. So by all means, do re-pitch. At worst, you will just waste $3 worth of yeast. At best, you will save much more in ingredients. And chance of success is pretty big.

Comment: Agreed with this, but it might not be a bad idea to re-pasteurize your mead, especially if you left it out for a while with no living, active yeast.  I think it's safe to say it will clear out. A big proportion of commercial yeast is likely dead by the time you pitch it anyway, under any circumstances.

Comment: @Bolwerk true, but if time was sort, boiling will only drive flavors of mead. Asked op for clarification.